# How to avoid Postfix sending emails without authentication even to users of the same domain

Tags: postfix

hopefully you could help me.

I just installed postfix and I am trying to configure to avoid spam.
The version I installed is **3.4.14**

I am trying to configure posfix to have this behavior:
From **External Sender** to **External Recipient**, must be **Rejected**, My result is **Rejected** config seems to OK

From **External Sender** to **Internal Recipient**, must be **Accepted**, My result is **Accepted** config seems to OK

From **Internal Sender (Not Authenticated)** to **External Recipient**, must be **Rejected**, My result is **Rejected** config seems to OK

From **Internal Sender (Not Authenticated)** to **Internal same sever domain Recipient**, must be **Rejected**, My result is **Accepted** config seems to **WRONG** and I don´t understand why

From **Internal Sender (Authenticated)** to **External Recipient**, must be **Accepted**, My result is **Accepted** config seems to OK validated by sending email to Gmail it was received fine, replied and received correctly in my postfix inbox.

From **Internal Sender (Authenticated)** to **Internal same sever domain Recipient**, must be **Accepted**, My result is **Accepted** config seems to OK.

This in the guide that I followed to install and configure it with virtual users through mysql
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin

I already read many times about smtpd_recipient_restrictons and smtpd_sender_restruction and tried many combinations of them but without any success

This part the log with wrong behavior configured on Postfix that should rejected and Not OK:

```
dummyserver@dummy:~$ telnet email.subdom.learning.com 25
Trying 177.138.109.12...
Connected to email.subdom.learning.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 email.subdom.learning.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo telnet.subdom.learning.com
250-email.subdom.learning.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
MAIL FROM: <user1@subdom.learning.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <user2@subdom.learning.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Any help that you can provide is welcomed

This is my main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_tls_auth_only = No 
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
        permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
myhostname = email.subdom.learning.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/24 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

and this is my master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```